# Loop through JSON object, return specific object

Tags: powershell

I'm using Azure Devops and I want to loop through a list of pull requests. I'm using [this API request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to retrieve a list of pull requests.

When I check the URL I see:

[image]

Which is correct. I have 3 open pull requests. What I want to do is check each object for a specific attribute called `sourceRefName`.

When there's a match I want to return the complete object:

[image]

I've tried:

```
$listOfPullRequestsURL = "https://dev.azure.com/*****/*****/_apis/git/repositories/*****/pullrequests?api-version=5.0"
$listOfPullRequests = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $listOfPullRequestsURL -Headers @{Authorization = $pat } -Method Get
Write-Host $listOfPullRequests
Write-Host $listOfPullRequests | ConvertFrom-Json

ForEach ($object in $listOfPullRequests) {
    Write-Host "### OBJECT ###"
    Write-Host $object
    Write-Host $object.sourceRefName
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

How do I go through each object? And is it possible to return the whole object based on 1 attribute?

Answer (score 1):

```
$listOfPullRequestsURL = "https://dev.azure.com/****/****/_apis/git/repositories/****/pullrequests?api-version=5.0"
$listOfPullRequests = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $listOfPullRequestsURL -Headers @{Authorization = $pat } -Method Get

$listOfPullRequests.value | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.sourceRefName -eq $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH) {
        Write-Host $_
    }
}
```

This shows the correct JSON object.

Comment: It seems PowerShell converts the [response JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#pull_requests_by_repository) into a PSCustomObject (which is why Write-Host displays it like a hashtable). As you've determined, the response payload exists within the PSCustomObject's System.Object[] property "value", so dereferencing it and passing the array to ForEach-Object gets the desired behavior. :)

Answer (score 0):

I understood you already took care of it.

Just wanted to add here - to avoid these stuff, I personally think it's more clean and creates less trouble to use hashtables.

In Powershell v6 It's easy to convert to hashtable with the built-in [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) flag `-AsHashtable`.

```
$hashPullRequests = $listOfPullRequests | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
```

and then loop over `$hashPullRequests` like any other hashtable.